# Dynamically set RTL / LTR in React-Native

Tags: right-to-left, react-native

I want to set my app'a direction dynamically, by a property.
React Native allows to set direction according to device's default language, but I want to select direction by locale property I have on my user's data.

Up until now, I used this code in my MainApplication.java to force only LTR for all users:

```
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
```

I'm looking now for a way to kind of switch the 'false' in code, to a boolean that changes according to my user's locale.
Have no idea how to achieve that...

Extra's info:

- Android device
- RN version: 0.40.0

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56248927/427622

Answer (score 2):

you can use `I18nManager` to force language direction

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //set user language b default english
    this.state = {
        lang: 'en'
    }
}


componentWillMount() {
          //get user lang form AsyncStorage 
    AsyncStorage.getItem('lang').then((value) => {
         //now you should forceRTL by Language and set Language in your states
        if ((value === 'ar' || value === 'fa' )) {
            I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
        } else {
            I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
        }
        return this.setState({
            lang: value 
        });
    }).done();
}
```