# React-native support RTL and LTR without changing device language

Tags: react-native, right-to-left

I have used react-native-i18n package for supporting international language. It is working but now I want my application can change RTL and LTR inside application according to language without changing device language. I used native base components in my application.
So I cannot change their styling and If it is possible then How?

I have created settings option to change language and it is changing but how to change LTR to RTL and RTL to LTR all the components of application.
If there is any solution please let me know.

Comment: In Android device developer settings, there is a checkbox to force RTL layout (without changing the language). Is this what you have been looking for?

Comment: Thank you, but I was not looking for any change in android device settings. And I got solution to my problem just by using direction styling in application.

Comment: Please add the way to set direction style for react application as your answer. SO encourages to accept your own answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: <Container style={{direction : this.state.applanguage == 'ar-US' ? "rtl" : "ltr"}}>    <Content>// your code goes here....</Content></Container>                                     and give textAlign : "left" it will adjust text alignment according to direction.

Comment: this solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446637/force-ltr-on-expo-on-android) works for me. enjoy it.

Comment: The solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446637/force-ltr-on-expo-on-android) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

from the react-native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#direction):

> direction specifies the directional flow of the user interface. The
>   default is `inherit`, except for `root` node which will have value
>   based on the current locale.

this means if you change the top `View` style direction to `"rtl"` all child components should inherit the direction.