# Force LTR on Expo on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, right-to-left

I am creating an app with React Native with Expo and I can't find a solution do force LTR (left-to-right) direction. Some of my users have its phone with RTL languages, but I only have English and Norwegian, so it doesn't make sense to show text in RTL in English.

I am also using i18next for translation.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Force LTR.

Comment: You can simulate RTL by enabling option in developer settings on android device or emulator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just found my solution after more digging.

On App.js import the following library:

```js
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";
```

Then right after the imports use the following code:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I can confirm it works on Expo 48 SDK.

Comment: this will not work for the initial load for the app, especially on production will not load at all, and the user has to delete and install the app again, which is bad for the user experience