# React-Native app & arabic phone settings layout gets broken

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have an app built in React-Native.
Whenever some user with arabic-phone settings(Reading right to left) tries to use it the layout gets broken.
Is there any way for me to force the phone to render the app reading-mode from left to right?
Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You have to restart app using some third party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58446637/3235603).

Quoting from there:

On App.js import the following library:

```
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";
```

Then right after the imports use the following code:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```